# web server mysql replication over slow adsl lines

Tags: linux, mysql, php, web-server, cluster

I would just like some recommendations.

Currently i am sitting with a vps server in europe that hosts my webserver and my mysql database. It servers our clients as a place to download documents and reports. We used to host the server on our company network which is 2 adsl lines not bonded just each line use for there own purpose one for our vpn to our international Head office and the other one for surfing. But my clients where complaning about slow downloads from the adsl lines (4Mb/512Kb)so only 512 Kb upload which rounds about to 60KBps max upload speed it will also limit the use of that line completely resulting in slow browsing speeds etc.

So i moved the server to a vps overseas and now all the clients are happy to be downloading at very high speeds but now the problem is that when we upload documents and anything else to it is takes very long due to our small upload speed.

Is there any efficient solution to upload the files to a local server and then every hour or so it replicates to our vps server overseas.

Is this a effective solution for my problem or are there better ways a addressing my current problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rsync in a cron job to push/pull changes to your webserver from local machine. Rsync can compress your data during transfer and also allows you to set bandwidth limit so that your browsing doesn't suffer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Comment: Ye was thinking of doing that will guve it a try and let you guys know how it works out.